# How do I make my changes as admin work for all users on station

Tags: windows-7, administrator

For example, shortcuts to terminal servers, programs pinned to start bar, etc. I have to go in and do it for every user that logs into the terminal. 
I'm new to IT and never got any training on differences between working as an admin vs user.

Comment: This question is extremely broad.  You combine creating a .wim and group policies.  What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly, the only "trying" I've done was to make the changes while logged in as administrator. We outsource our infrastructure so they cover the group policies. I was hoping there was a settings in windows for "make this effective for all users" or something.

Comment: You make the changes the generalize the installion by Sysprep and creating a new .wim used to install Windows.  There is no "single" way to do what your asking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For desktop icons/shortcuts put them in the Users\Public\Desktop folder. That way they show show up on everyones desktop

Comment: Why was this put on hold and why did I get downgraded. The question is a very good question. What I don't or can't see is where wim or images come in to play. You shouldn't have dinged the question in the first place let alone dinging me for giving him the answer he was looking for. If I am missing something then why don't you take the time to point it out politely rather then Ting off like an idiot?

Comment: Agreed. Also, that was exactly the answer I was looking for. The only addition I would make for anyone else that runs into the same question, is that the Desktop folder in Users\Public may be a hidden folder, so be aware of that. But I tested it out and it's working exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you ZiggyStardust, for being helpful and not ornery like some.

Comment: Excellent point. To take it a step farther if you want to add a "global" entry to everyone's start menu it is in C:\ProgramData\MIcrosoft\Windows\Start Menu. It too is hidden.